# Filtering records based on string array PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string array in PHP called **groups**. The array looks something like this based on user input: **groups[All, Sales]**.

**Example: (UPDATED TABLE SCHEMA)**

```
groups[] = ['Sales', 'All']

            ANNOUNCEMENT
 |description|masterID|  groupName   |
=======================================
 | hello     | 1      | All, Final,  |
 | greetings | 2      | Sales, All,  |
 | demo      | 3      | Final,       |
```

So from above table it should only return "**hello**" and "**greetings**" as **output** because **groups[]** has **Sales** and **All** as row 1 has All and row 2 has both. Please help. I am an amateur in SQL and PHP both.

**My current try:**

```
SELECT * FROM announcement WHERE groupName REGEXP '(Sales | All)'
```

Output:

```
No rows affected
```

Comment: NEVER store comma separated values in database. To retrieve them you'll need a full text search through LIKE "%Final%".

Comment: I would suggest to normalize your database. Create a new table with group names and have another table with masterID and groupId. That would make your life a lot easier going forward as well.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions, but this is what I have to work with. Can't change it otherwise I would have easily solved this issue. Can you show me a way to work with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. I guess, your groups should really be in string format: `groups[] = ['Final', 'All', 'Test']`.
2. This `$search = implode('|', $groups)` will produce a string `Final|All|Test`.
3. Now you need to put this string into your query to search by either or the words. So, this is `WHERE groupName REGEXP '({$search})'`. Don't forget about quotes inside the query and so that they don't clash with quotes you put your whole query in.

Comment: I changed my table schema to make it: `|description|masterID|groupName|`. Please check my updated question above.

Comment: The only error was REGEXP '($search)'. It should have been a rounded bracket. It works now :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does Perl-like regular expressions. Construct a query similar to this:

```
SELECT description
  FROM announcement NATURAL JOIN master
 WHERE groupName REGEXP '\\b(Final|All|Test)\\b';
```

Comment: But how do I get each group array element in between REGEXP?

Comment: I left that as an exercise -- but something like `$query = 'SELECT ... REGEXP \'\\\\b(' . implode('|', $groups) . ')\\\\b\''` would work.

Comment: I am pretty amateur. Although I am searching it on google on how to do it, if you could just get me through, I would be grateful to you.